# larvel blade templates and elequent models -- how to get first element in many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following eloquent models (removed code to make it simple for this problem). I am trying to get the first image

```
class Design extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = ['id','tags','keywords'];

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DesignImage::class);
    }
   ...
}

class DesignImage extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function design()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Design::class);
    }
}
```

Then I have the following code that gets passed to a blade template

```
$data['designs'] = Design::where('quantity','>',0)->get();
return view('mailings.form',$data);
```

Template (Works fine; I get the name of all images

```
@foreach($design->images as $image)
    {{ $image->name }}
@endforeach
```

But if I try

```
{{ $design->images->first()->name }}
```

I get Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`

If I try

```
{{ $design->images[0]->name }}
```

I get Undefined offset: 0

However if I do

```
@json ($design->images->first())
```

I get (valid)

{"id":1,"name":"Image 1 Design 1","thumb":"images/main_thumb.jpg","image":"images/main_large.jpg","design_id":1,"created_at":"2018-12-11 20:10:03","updated_at":"2018-12-11 20:10:03","deleted_at":null}

How do I get the first image in a blade template? Why am I getting this odd output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occurs because latest one `$design` does not have `image`. Try this code

```
@foreach($designs as $design)
    // your code
    @php
        $firstImage = $design->images()->first();
    @endphp
    {{ !empty($firstImage->name) ? $firstImage->name : ''}}
    // other part ofcode
@endforeach
```

Also you can optimize this code using in controller

```
$data['designs'] = Design::where('quantity','>',0)->with('images')->get();
return view('mailings.form',$data);
```

In view

```
@foreach($designs as $design)
    // your code
    @php
        $firstImage = $design->images->first();
    @endphp
    {{ !empty($firstImage->name) ? $firstImage->name : ''}}
    // other part ofcode
@endforeach
```

Comment: still error Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: try changed answer

Comment: @ChrisMuench are you try it??

Comment: For more optimize query see [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)